# Why is this sed command replacing line instead of appending to it?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have a file with the following line:

```
some.url=failover:(nio://localhost:12345)?maxAttempts=5&timeout=10000
```

I want to completely replace this line with a different one:

```
some.url=failover:(nio://someserver.com:6789)?something=10&another=6
```

but the following sed command is appending to the line, not replacing it, any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
sed -i 's~^some.url=.*$~some.url=failover:(nio://someserver.com6789)?something=10&another=6~'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the `&` in the replacement part. Because it has a special meaning(prints the matched string).

```
sed 's~^some\.url=.*$~some.url=failover:(nio://someserver.com6789)?something=10\&another=6~' file
```

**Example:**

```
$ echo 'some.url=failover:(nio://localhost:12345)?maxAttempts=5&timeout=10000' | sed 's~^some.url=.*$~some.url=failover:(nio://someserver.com6789)?something=10\&another=6~'
some.url=failover:(nio://someserver.com6789)?something=10&another=6
```

Comment: still so fast. you just forget the (optional need) `.` in search pattern :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i '/^some.url=.*$/ c\
some.url=failover:(nio://someserver.com6789)?something=10&another=6'
# OR
sed -i 's~^some\.url=.*$~some.url=failover:(nio://someserver.com6789)?something=10\&another=6~'
```

use `c` if change the whole line (but it goes directly to next line, so not if next action needed)

you have `&` in your replacement patterne, escape it. It mean 'all search pattern content' so you duplicate the content inside your replacment